# Align Dataset partitioning to table partitioning scheme

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I am writing to a table partitioned by month. I know that my data is ≈100MB per partition, no skew - it is going to fit within single HDFS block and I want to ensure that every partition gets a single file written. I also know the exact number of months in my dataset (which is something between 1 and 10), therefore:

```
ds.repartition(nMonths, $"month").write.<options>.insertInto(<...>)
```

This works. However I'm thinking from here... As Spark uses key's hash to determine the partition, I have no guarantee that every partition will receive a single month's data. The more partitions I have, the less likely this actually is - right?

Does it make sense then to increase the number of partitions above number of distinct keys?

```
ds.repartition(nMonths * 3, $"month").write.<options>.insertInto(<...>)
```

Lots of partitions will be empty, but this shouldn't be that much of a pain (should it?) and we're reducing the probability that some unlucky partitions get 3x/4x data, increasing overall execution time. Does this make sense? Is there any rule of thumb regarding the factor? Or any other approach to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be super-safe you can use [range partitioning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartitionByRange(partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]), something like:

```
ds.repartitionByRange(nMonths,$"month").write...
```

This way you also won't be having empty partitions, which in turn means you won't produce zero-size files in HDFS too.

Comment: Cool, I'm surprised to see how nicely it also handles ranges like 201907..202006 (from `Int` perspective there's a 201913..201999 gap here).